# Drawing line in Editor and not at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, line

i'm trying to visualize lines in the Unity editor and not only at runtime, is there a specific method to call in my script to do that? Is there any script already implementing this thing?
thanks a lot!!

Comment: Read up on gizmos

Answer (score 1):

if you mean debug lines gizmos, there are few ways to achieve that.
Easiest one is

```
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(fromPosition,toPosition);
    }
```

Where `fromPosition,toPosition` are `Vector3`